# Issue in Executing the jquery program for multi select list with (table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Please Don't make it duplicate i have a code please refer that and let me where i'm doing wrong** Hello guys i have program which deals with the multi select list where I have implemented such functionality where user can Add or Remove item from left side list to right side list ("<" and ">").**This Totally works fine** Again i have added a Table which contains the right side (selected list values) for this code is :
**HTML:** **In this "sourceHeaderFields" contains the list where we are selecting list adding to the "sourceHeaderFields"**

```
<h2><strong>Select features from Seed data:</strong> </h2>
                <select id="sourceHeaderFields" name="sourceHeaderFields" multiple="multiple" 
                        style="width:210Px;height:150px;margin-left: 100px;">
                </select>
                <select id="sourceHeaderFields" name="targetHeaderFields" multiple="multiple" 
                        style="width:210Px; height:150px">
                </select>
            <br>
                <input type="button" id="leftall" value="<<" style="margin-left: 250px;"/>
                <input type="button" id="left" value="<" />
                <input type="button" id="right" value=">" />
                <input type="button" id="rightall" value=">>" />
            <br />
        <br></br> 

        <h2> <strong> Default Values for the Selected Headers: </strong> </h2>
            <table id="defaultValuesTable">
        </table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () { 

    function moveItems(origin, dest) {
        $(origin).find(':selected').appendTo(dest);
    }
$('#left').click(function () {
        selectedValue1 = $('#targetHeaderFields').remove(':selected').val()
        //console.log(selectedValue1);
        moveItems('#targetHeaderFields', '#sourceHeaderFields');

        $("#defaultValuesTable").remove().append("<tr id='"+selectedValue+"'><td>" 
                                        +selectedValue+"</td><td><input type='text'></tr>");

    });

    $('#right').on('click', function () {
        selectedValue = $('#sourceHeaderFields').find(':selected').val()
        console.log(selectedValue);
        moveItems('#sourceHeaderFields', '#targetHeaderFields');
        debugger;
        //Populate the table with the field
        $("#defaultValuesTable").append("<tr id='"+selectedValue+"'><td>" 
                                        +selectedValue+"</td><td><input type='text'></tr>");


    });
```

Multilist works fine **but problem is this line:for table list****Please go this for live code working:** https://jsfiddle.net/8jbp47zq/ not sure how to paste a csv file to get the list

```
 $("#defaultValuesTable").remove().append("<tr id='"+selectedValue+"'><td>" 
                                        +selectedValue+"</td><td><input type='text'></tr>");
```

**Here when i'm adding anything its adding a text bar for the table with accoresponding list name but when i'm removing its not removing one by one at once its remove all...i want to remove the table list one by one not at once for that i have tried many way:**

```
//$("#defaultValuesTable").remove(id="+selectedValue1+");
and
//$("#defaultValuesTable").children("tr").remove();
and
//$("#defaultValuesTable").remove().append(id="+selectedValue1+");
```

**none of these worked please help..If you guys need more info please tell me ill give...I have added a pic of web UI please refer that...thnx**
[image]

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Kaushik i didn't get u? fiddle?

Comment: Why do type all in bold?

Comment: you need to create a demo code, which is not working and then tell what is expected. use this link to create a code, this you can execute and see the results. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @quirimmo please don't go with that please help me with my code i just want to make point with bold nothing else

Comment: You delete the table, and then append a tr, but the table is not anymore there. Try changing your `remove()` with `empty()`

Comment: @Kaushik  its not possible its really big program to paste here i'm doing lots of thing just my question is i want to remove a list one at time byr (Default Values for the Selected Headers) which given in pic ...by using above its removing all list at once these all thing want it from (Default Values for the Selected Headers) not from mutilist (Select features from Seed data:)

Comment: @quirimmo its not working i want to remove a list one at time byr (Default Values for the Selected Headers) which given in pic ...by using above its removing all list at once these all thing want it from (Default Values for the Selected Headers) not from mutilist (Select features from Seed data:)

Comment: If you want my personal suggestion, clean up your question, make a snippet and show us what's the issue and what is the desired behaviour. If you don't take the time to create a snippet for yourself, why should you think that someone will do it?

Comment: @quirimmo i never wanted that anyone will write code for me js thing is totally new for me that's why i was asking that is that way of writting code correct or not any wany i'm pasting my whole program on fiddle if its will done will paste the url here..

Comment: @quirimmo this is the url : https://jsfiddle.net/8jbp47zq/ but how you guys will get the csv file i'm selecting

Comment: @Kaushik please go with this page :https://jsfiddle.net/8jbp47zq/

Comment: @snehilsingh can you check this now? - https://jsfiddle.net/8jbp47zq/1/

Comment: @Kaushik thnx a lot bro its working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the remove process. I've updated the code.

```js
//A drop-down list
$(document).ready(function() {

  for (var i = 1970; i <= 2018; i++) {
    var fromYearSelect = document.getElementById("fromYear");
    var toYearSelect = document.getElementById("toYear");

    var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
    fromYearSelect.options.add(option);
    option.text = i;
    option.value = i;


    var option2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
    toYearSelect.options.add(option2);
    option2.text = i;
    option2.value = i;
  }
});

$(function() {

  function moveItems(origin, dest) {
    $(origin).find(':selected').appendTo(dest);
  }

  function moveAllItems(origin, dest) {
    $(origin).children().appendTo(dest);
  }

  $('#left').click(function() {
    debugger;
    selectedValue1 = $('#targetHeaderFields').remove(':selected').val()
    //console.log(selectedValue1);
    moveItems('#targetHeaderFields', '#sourceHeaderFields');

    debugger; // fixed below line. 
    $('#'+selectedValue1, "#defaultValuesTable").remove();
    //$("#defaultValuesTable").children("tr").remove();
    //$("#defaultValuesTable").remove().append(id="+selectedValue1+");

    // $("#defaultValuesTable").remove().append("<tr id='" + selectedValue + "'><td>" +
      // selectedValue + "</td><td><input type='text'></tr>");

  });

  $('#right').on('click', function() {
    selectedValue = $('#sourceHeaderFields').find(':selected').val()
    console.log(selectedValue);
    moveItems('#sourceHeaderFields', '#targetHeaderFields');
    debugger;
    //Populate the table with the field
    $("#defaultValuesTable").append("<tr id='" + selectedValue + "'><td>" +
      selectedValue + "</td><td><input type='text'></tr>");


  });

  $('#leftall').on('click', function() {
    moveAllItems('#targetHeaderFields', '#sourceHeaderFields');
  });

  $('#rightall').on('click', function() {
    moveAllItems('#sourceHeaderFields', '#targetHeaderFields');
  });

  $('#populateHeaderFields').on('click', function() {

    alert("Inside populate list");

    var files = ('#source_fileName').files;
    alert("Files Count - " + files);

  });

  $('#upload-form').on('change', function(evt) {
    //alert('File content changed');
    debugger;

    var filesCount = evt.target.files.length;
    for (i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
      var file = evt.target.files[i];
      if (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        /*
        reader.onload = function(e) { 
            var contents = e.target.result;             
            var ct = reader.result;
            var words = ct.split(' ');            
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
        */

        // Read our file to an ArrayBuffer
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

        // Handler for onloadend event.  Triggered each time the reading operation is completed (success or failure) 
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
          // Get the Array Buffer
          var data = evt.target.result;

          // Grab our byte length
          var byteLength = data.byteLength;

          // Convert to conventional array, so we can iterate though it
          var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data, 0);

          // Used to store each character that makes up CSV header
          var headerString = '';

          // Iterate through each character in our Array
          for (var i = 0; i < byteLength; i++) {
            // Get the character for the current iteration
            var char = String.fromCharCode(ui8a[i]);

            // Check if the char is a new line
            if (char.match(/[^\r\n]+/g) !== null) {

              // Not a new line so lets append it to our header string and keep processing
              headerString += char;

            } else {
              // We found a new line character, stop processing
              break;
            }
          }
          //Iterate through the list and populate the select element..
          $.each(headerString.split(","), function(i, e) {
            $("#sourceHeaderFields").append($("<option>", {
              text: e,
              value: e
            }));

          });
          //  if len(headerString)!= 1{
          //  alert("headerString Donot match");
          // }else{
          console.log(headerString);
          console.log("Next Read");

        };
      } else {
        alert("Failed to load file");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> upload </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/solar/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="mx-auto" style="width:500px;">
          <h1>Large Data Generation</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form id="upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="file-selector">
          <p>
            <strong>Source File: </strong>
            <input id="source_fileName" type="file" name="source_fileName" accept="csv/*" multiple style="
       margin-left: 10px;" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <strong>Location Type:</strong>
        <input type="radio" name="target" value="BrowserDownload" checked>Browse Local
        <input type="radio" name="target" value="dumpToS3"> S3 Remote
        <br> </br>

        <h2><strong>Select features from Seed data:</strong> </h2>
        <select id="sourceHeaderFields" name="sourceHeaderFields" multiple="multiple" style="width:210Px;height:150px;margin-left: 100px;">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
       </select>
        <select id="targetHeaderFields" name="targetHeaderFields" multiple="multiple" style="width:210Px; height:150px">
       </select>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="leftall" value="<<" style="margin-left: 250px;" />
        <input type="button" id="left" value="<" />
        <input type="button" id="right" value=">" />
        <input type="button" id="rightall" value=">>" />
        <br />
        <br></br>
        <h2><strong>Default Values for the Selected Headers:</strong></h2>
        <table id="defaultValuesTable">
        </table>
        <br>
        <div>
          <br>
        </div>
        <div id="div_records">
          <strong>Record Count: </strong>
          <input id="records" type="text" name="records" value="1000" style="margin-left: 5px;">
          <br> <br> <br>
          <strong>From Year: </strong>
          <select id="fromYear" name="fromYear" style="margin-left: 30px;"></select>
          <strong style="margin-left:20px">To Year: </strong>
          <select id="toYear" name="toYear" style="margin-left: 5px;"></select>
          <br></br>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate Data" id="upload-button">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: thnx for the solution one more thing i want to ask that i want to call this Html table that is "defaultValuesTable" in my python code for that i have written code like :"TableHeaders = request.form.get("defaultValuesTable")" I'm calling it by its id but its not containing anything its showing None it should have some text values like "Hi" and "Hello" i don't know why if possible please help

Comment: @snehilsingh I did not understood your question

Comment: at "Default Values for the Selected Headers:" when ever we select any features it will give that header name with text field now i want to write something on that text field and call it to my python program

Answer (score 1):

### Remove multiple/all rows one by one from a table with delay use below code.

```
var i=0;
$('#defaultValuesTable tr').each(function() {    
    var dly=200;
    $(this).delay(i*dly).queue(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

    i++; 
});
```

Change value of dly to increase/decrease delay

Comment: thnx for the answer but its not working for me anyway i got my answer but if change your first line of code then it will work fine for me "$('#'+selectedValue1, "#defaultValuesTable").each(function() {  " anyway thnx..